# Mercurial Case folding issue

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

This is not a unique problem that has not been there in the past, but none of the solutions have helped me yet.

My Case - A huge repository that was maintained by Perforce(by my company's central SCM) team. Now they change something, and all individual teams manage their own SCM and use the main perforce only for regular updates(Don't ask me why - i have no say in this)

however my problem - we moved to Mercurial for our team's projects.

Its huge - about 300k files and cross platform compilable.

The mercurial repo that i set up works well with Linux, but on windows i get the case folding error and not able to checkout or clone repos.

I tried the solutions from https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CaseFolding

and the result looks like this

1. hgfold extension - does not work - it throws some unknown python exception and someone faced this issue and the maintainer of the extension is aware of it but has no immediate fix.
2. It is not possible to simply rename the files, our repo will break, i have to live with the same file name, and in linux it works great and are being used. So i don't know if renaming is an option.
3. Perforce handles it well, but as i said i have no say here.

So is there any other way out here??
Can SVN handle casefoldings well?? Any help is of very use to me.

Comment: Do you really need case folding anyway? As long as you don't have files whose names differ only in case, you shouldn't have to worry about it.

Comment: Perforce also can't handle clashes in case folding because there is no solution how to do this automatically.  And as @Ringding already correctly mentions you only need case folding if there are clashes.  But if there are clashes you have to fix them anyway if you want to work on case insensitive OS

Comment: @Ringding - Yes i do have clashes, infact lots in our repository. It was originally managed by Perforce.

Comment: @Peer Stritzinger Yes i do have clashes, i guess the reason why it works now it because, those files are in different folders. Because mercurial doesn ot maintain according to directories in the central repo, when i try to clone i get this error, but the problematic files are in different directories, So if a SCM tools maintains files by directories i should ahve no problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is: 1. if there are files named the same in different directories (no matter what the cases) -> this is not a clash at all and does not matter.  2. if there is a clash then it also has to be in the same directory.

Comment: Did you try running the find command line I mentioned in my answer on the Linux side?  If yes: was there any output??

Comment: @Peer Stritzinger - Thanks., i don't have access to that computer during the weekend, i will do it first thing on Monday., but when i got the error, i got saying "abort file kernel/mips/a/b/c/inc_SOMETHING.ko clashing with kernel/x86/a/b/c/in_something.ko something like this., on Monday i shall copy paste the exact error and try your find command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a chapter in the Mercurial book chapter [Case sensitivity](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/file-names-and-pattern-matching.html#sec%3anames%3acase)

> Just find a nearby Linux or Unix box, clone the problem repository
>   onto it, and use Mercurial's hg rename command to change the names of
>   any offending files or directories so that they will no longer cause
>   case folding conflicts. Commit this change, hg pull or hg push it
>   across to your Windows or MacOS system, and hg update to the revision
>   with the non-conflicting names.

The problem is that there is not really a working automated way to resolve cases clashes.  Filenames are often referenced in other files like Makefiles or include statements or config file reads in source.  So any way to resolve this automatically is prone to break something.

From the comments on the above chapters a few tips:

> Grant Baillie 2009-08-13 On a Mac, you can also do this repair on your
>   computer by creating a disk image containing a case-sensitive
>   filesystem. Launch Disk Utility (in /Applications/Utilities), click
>   File -> New -> Blank Disk Image ..., and choose "Mac OS Extended
>   (Journaled, Case-sensitive)" as the Volume Format.

and you could use

```
find . -print | sort -f | uniq -di
```

on a case sensitive filesystem to find all filenames that clash on case.